# How does a firewall receiving an image file approve it?

Tags: firewall

I was recently told that a Firewall configuration for the WatchGuard device does not allow the user to login and alter the configurations. Instead, you send an encrypted image file containing the configurations.

**So how does the Firewall approve the encrypted file and change its settings?**

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Watchguard [says](https://www.watchguard.com/help/docs/fireware/12/en-US/Content/en-US/system_status/config_pages_about_web.html) "With Fireware Web UI, you can monitor and manage any Firebox that runs Fireware OS. You do not have to install any extra software on your computer. The only software you must have is a web browser."  Images of the login process are [here](https://www.watchguard.com/help/docs/fireware/12/en-US/Content/en-US/system_status/connecting_about_web.html).

As with most equipment, you can save and restore [backup images](https://www.watchguard.com/help/docs/fireware/12/en-US/Content/en-US/backup_upgrade_recovery/firebox_backup_images_about_c.html): Watchguard's are encrypted.

To manage a number of Watchguard machines, you can use a method of image deployment, where a central system maintains the configuration images of multiple machines.  [DOC](https://www.watchguard.com/help/docs/fireware/12/en-US/Content/en-US/_Fireware_intro/centralized_management.html?tocpath=Centrally%20Manage%20Your%20Fireboxes%7C_____0)